# Phonegap build, enable secondary portrait orientation?

Tags: orientation, phonegap-build

Phonegap build by default apparently excludes rotation to secondary portrait orientation. Is it possible to enable it?

Using PhoneGap build service and iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, unless you explicitly specify the device orientation, a platform-specific default is used. So if is supported by Cordova by default, it will work on PhoneGap Build too.

Formal quote from [PhoneGap Build documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences):

> Device orientation; possible values are default, landscape, or portrait. Please note that default means both landscape and portrait are enabled. If you want to use each platform's default settings (usually portrait only), remove this tag from your config.xml file.

If you want to explicitly control the orientation of screen, you should check the great plugin from GitHub user *yoik* called [*Cordova Screen Orientation Plugin*](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation).